# how to create very first view for Swift 3

Tags: swift, view, swift3

Hi I have made a ViewController.

But I don't know how to add very first view right after an app is tapped.

I added below codes in ViewController.swift

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

the FirstViewController appears after the app tapped and shows white background for about a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first launch your app, the LaunchScreen.storyboard is displayed, as a transition while your app is loading.  You can customise this in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

check the option 'is initial view Controller' for that firstViewController from the storyboard.

Comment: Yes I did but still it shows white background for a second then appears the FirstViewController

Answer (score 1):

You can set initial view controller programmatically or via storyboard

***Method 1***:programmatically--

Set storyboard-identifire for `Viewcontroller` in `Main.storyboard` file 
like [image]

After that set `rootviewController` in `Appdelegate` class.

```
 import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let redViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        window?.rootViewController = redViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

For setting up with navigation controller use `UINavigationController` -

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)


        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController") as! viewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

***Method 2***:Via storyboard--
Go to respective storyboard & select Is Initial View Controller

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is helpful for me to understand the initial view controller. Thanks!